# Error in outer indentation level for IoT device Distance sensor

Tags: python, if-statement, raspberry-pi, distance, sensors

We are a student from college doing our project, which is inter and outer counter that counts the student who enters the room and leaves it. A problem in line 30 says there's outer indentation and trackback error, so we have two sensors ( sensor1, sensor2). When sensor1 calculates the distance, then sensor2 means the person is entering. On the opposite, also we don't have any idea about indentation.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQI59.png)

Comment: Your line 30 have 1 space in it, just remove it

Answer (score 0):

[image]

It seems that you added an extra space at the beginning of the line `30`. If you don't correctly add spaces to your Python code, it will throw an indentation error.